# jQuery loop through array by appending div

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

This is probably something simple, but I can't figure it out. Thanks! 
    http://jsfiddle.net/8DGgg/1/

```
  var listP ={"PEOPLE": [
       {  "name": "Joe",  "age": "1"  },
       {  "name": "Jim",  "age": "2" },
       {  "name": "Jessica",  "age": "3" }
       ]};


 for(var j in listP.PEOPLE) { 
     $("#dir").append( "<div class=\"whoWrap\">" );
     $(".whoWrap").append( listP.PEOPLE[j].name + " " + j );
     $("#dir").append("</div>");
    }
```

Desired result:

```
  <div id="dir">
      <div class="whoWrap">Joe 0</div>
      <div class="whoWrap">Jim 1</div>
      <div class="whoWrap">Jessica 2</div>
      </div>
```

Actual result:

```
      <div id="dir">
          <div class="whoWrap">Joe 0Jim 1Jessica 2</div>
          <div class="whoWrap">Jim 1Jessica 2</div>
          <div class="whoWrap">Jessica 2</div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do this way:

```
for(var j in listP.PEOPLE) { 

 $("#dir").append( "<div class=\"whoWrap\">"+listP.PEOPLE[j].name + " " + j +"</div>" );

 $("#dir").append("</div>");

}
```

you don't need to append in **whoWrap** just append in same **dir** div and it will be fine.

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/ze27X/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `.whoWrap` selector matches all previous elements that have already been appended in previous iterations. To resolve, reduce the elements using `.last()`.

Also it would be a good idea to add `#dir` to the selector so it only targets elements within that.

```
 $("#dir > .whoWrap").last().append( listP.PEOPLE[j].name + " " + j );
```

---

The whole thing would be better written as:

```
$.each(listP.PEOPLE, function(index){
    $("#dir").append(
        $('<div>')
            .addClass('whoWrap')
            .text(this.name + " " + index)
    );
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/D3AS2/)**

- Working with DOM elements (or jQuery objects) is better than dealing with raw HTML.
- For in loops have issues when looping arrays, use jQuery `$.each` or a basic for loop.

Answer (score 1):

$(".whoWrap") selected all div's whose class matched. Hence causing the duplication. Modify your code as below.

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/CodingDawg/8DGgg/2/

```
for (var j in listP.PEOPLE) {
   var div = "<div class='whoWrap'>" + listP.PEOPLE[j].name + " " + j + "</div>"
   $("#dir").append(div);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

   var listP ={"PEOPLE": [{  "name": "Joe",  "age": "1" },{  "name": "Jim",  "age": "2"  },{  "name": "Jessica",  "age": "3"}]};


      for(var j in listP.PEOPLE) { 
          var whoWrap=$('<div class=\"whoWrap\"></div>');

         whoWrap.append( listP.PEOPLE[j].name + " " + j );
         $("#dir").append(whoWrap);

    }


    });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is that you append content to this class $(".whoWrap") so It'll match all of them.

Here is your jsfiddle working  http://jsfiddle.net/mrodriguezr/8DGgg/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var listP ={"PEOPLE": [
           {  "name": "Joe",  "age": "1" },
           {  "name": "Jim",  "age": "2"  },
           {  "name": "Jessica",  "age": "3"}
           ]};

 for(var j in listP.PEOPLE) { 
      var $whoDiv = $('<div>', {'class' : 'whoWrap'}).append(listP.PEOPLE[j].name + " " + j );

      $("#dir").append($whoDiv);
      $("#dir").append($whoDiv);
    }
});
```